# Tkinter OptionMenu (Python 3) - Resetting menu after command executed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

Dear StackOverflow community,

I am building a Tkinter GUI for my football season handling program. In specific, I have a class containing the visual representation of a game input feature. This class contains OptionMenu widgets that prompts the user to select teams and their scores, respectively.

The issue here is that I can not work out how to reset the OptionMenu after submitting a game. Let me provide the code before I elaborate;

```
class Game_View():
'''
This class contains the visual representation of the game input feature.
'''
def __init__(self, frame, parent, season, selected_hometeam, selected_awayteam, selected_homegoal, selected_awaygoal):
    self.frame=frame
    self.parent=parent
    self.season=season
    self.insert_game_prompt()
    self.insert_input_fixture_button()
    self.selected_hometeam=selected_hometeam
    self.selected_homegoal=selected_homegoal
    self.selected_awayteam=selected_awayteam
    self.selected_awaygoal=selected_awaygoal

def insert_game_prompt(self):
    '''
    This method creates the drop-down menus that allow the user to provide information about a fixture.
    In specific, the user inputs the home team, the away team, and their scored goals.
    '''
    self.goal_list=[]
    i=0
    while i<11:
        self.goal_list.append(i)
        i+=1
    #The record for scored goals in the a Premier League match ever is 9;
    # (Man Utd v. Ipswich town, 9 - 0, 4th of March 1995.)
    # Hence, this program allows the user to exceed this record by 1, as the
    # upper limit of possible scored goals is 10.

    window_title_1=Label(self.frame, text="Home Team:", bg='grey')
    window_title_1.pack()

    self.selected_hometeam=StringVar()
    self.selected_hometeam.set('Provide Team')
    hometeam_prompt=OptionMenu(self.frame, self.selected_hometeam, *self.season.team_names, command=self.assign_hometeam)
    hometeam_prompt.config(bg='grey')
    hometeam_prompt.pack()

    self.selected_homegoal=StringVar()
    self.selected_homegoal.set('Provide Score')
    homegoal_prompt=OptionMenu(self.frame, self.selected_homegoal, *self.goal_list, command=self.assign_homegoal)
    homegoal_prompt.config(bg='grey')
    homegoal_prompt.pack()

    window_title_2=Label(self.frame, text="\nAway Team:", bg='grey')
    window_title_2.pack()

    self.selected_awayteam=StringVar()
    self.selected_awayteam.set('Provide Team')
    awayteam_prompt=OptionMenu(self.frame, self.selected_awayteam, *self.season.team_names, command=self.assign_awayteam)
    awayteam_prompt.config(bg='grey')
    awayteam_prompt.pack()

    self.selected_awaygoal=StringVar()
    self.selected_awaygoal.set('Provide Score')
    awaygoal_prompt=OptionMenu(self.frame, self.selected_awaygoal, *self.goal_list, command=self.assign_awaygoal)
    awaygoal_prompt.config(bg='grey')
    awaygoal_prompt.pack()

def assign_hometeam(self, team):
    '''
    This method updates the class attribute with the home team selected by the user.
    '''
    self.selected_hometeam=team

def assign_awayteam(self, team):
    '''
    This method updates the class attribute with the away team selected by the user.
    '''
    self.selected_awayteam=team

def assign_homegoal(self, goal):
    '''
    This method updates the class attribute with the goals scored by the home team.
    '''
    self.selected_homegoal=goal

def assign_awaygoal(self, goal):
    '''
    This method updates the class attribute with the goals scored by the away team.
    '''
    self.selected_awaygoal=goal

def insert_input_fixture_button(self):
    '''
    This method inserts a button that the user presses when he/she wants to input a match entry.
    '''
    input_fixture_button=Button(self.frame, height=1, width=10, text='Input fixture', highlightbackground='grey')
    input_fixture_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.submit_fixture)
    input_fixture_button.pack()

def submit_fixture(self, a):
    '''
    When the Insert input button is pressed, this method sends the information provided by the user to the match handling logic
    in the Season class. Secondly, it prompts a new rendering of the table. Thirdly, it resets the input fixture button.
    '''
    self.season.submit_match_data(self.selected_hometeam, self.selected_awayteam, self.selected_homegoal, self.selected_awaygoal)
    self.parent.render_season_view()
```

As you can see, clicking the Input Fixture button triggers the submit_fixture method, which uses the currently selected OptionMenu options (hence, its class attributes) in its call to the match logic in a different class. Currently, the OptionMenu selections remain after clicking the Input Fixture button, but I would rather like them to reset to "Provide Team (Score)", respectively.

I have tried making the following "re-render"-method that would be called last in the submit_fixture method;

(1) Destroys the OptionMenus through .destroy() / .forget()

(2) Resets the class attributes (selected_home(away)_team(goal))

(3) Calls self.insert_game_prompt() to re-create the OptionMenus

However, no matter how I configure this re-render method, the options remain after clicking the Input Fixture-button. Firstly; Is there an easier way to reset the options rather than destroying/creating them? Naturally I have searched the forum without luck. Secondly, would you have a clue with regard to what I do wrong?

Best,
JG